# Is it alright to create an object of modelandview in each method of the class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelandview

I have following controller which is serving different requests. I am wondering if the way that I create ModelAndView is correct? I am creating one object in each method. Is there any better approach?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showNames() {
    ...
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("names");
    model.addObject ....
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showNameDetails(@PathVariable String name) {
    ...
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("name");
    model.addObject ...
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{name}/{item}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showItemsOfName(@PathVariable String name,
        @PathVariable String item) {
    ...
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("item");
    model.addObject ....
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask Spring to inject the Model for you, and then return the view name from the method, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showNames(Model model) {
    ...
    model.addObject ....
    return "names";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showNameDetails(@PathVariable String name, Model model) {
    ...
    model.addObject ...
    return "name";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{name}/{item}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showItemsOfName(@PathVariable String name,
        @PathVariable String item, Model model) {
    ...
    model.addObject ....
    return "item";
}
```

It's a bit cleaner, and less code.

Comment: it does not accept addObject methods anymore! Imported library is org.springframework.ui.Model; I suppose I should replace them with addAttribute right?